# bash scripts - need help with syntax

Tags: bash, shell-script, syntax

I am reading the last line of 4 different files and grep for a certain string.
Based on the string, I need to rename the source file. All 4 files have a different grep string and eventual target name.

```
if tail -n1 $f | grep $string -e $string; then cp $f to file.new
else tail -n1 $f |grep $sting2 -e $string2; then cp $f to file2.new
```

Comment: What is the question ? If you have syntax error, always first pass your scrip to https://shellcheck.net

Comment: `cp $f file.new` - no `to`.

Comment: The grep command looks wrong. Apart from 'sting2' you normally need a `-e` for each string.

Comment: @NickD, `cp $f file.new` is still wrong. Should rather be `cp -- "$f" file.new` in bash (`--` needed in every shell, `"..."` only in those shells like bash where unquoted expansions undergo split+glob)

Answer (score 0):

1. you should quote all the variable substitutions, or otherwise a blank or other shell-magic character in the value would tear it into separate arguments or produce unwanted effects.
2. grep should have an "-e" before each search string, not just before the second one.  As the strings seem to be the same, you can leave one out, of course.
3. as mentioned in a comment, leave the "to" out from the "cp".
4. There's a typo in first occurrence of $string2 (the r is missing) - if this was a copy&paste, then the original code might have the same typo.

```
    if tail -n1 "$f" | grep -e "$string"; then cp "$f" file.new
    else tail -n1 "$f" |grep -e "$string2"; then cp "$f" file2.new
    else ...  string3    file3
    else ...  string4    file4
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`tail -n1 $f` is not the correct syntax to get the last line of a file whose path is stored in `$f`. The correct syntax is either `tail -n1 -- "$f"` or better (so it also works  for a file called `-`): `tail -n1 < "$f"`.

Same, to check whether that line contains `$string` or `$string2`, the syntax would be `grep -F -e "$string" -e "$string2"`.

In any case, in bash and most other Bourne-like shell, leaving parameter expansions unquoted hardly ever make sense.

Here, it rather seems like you should use a `case` statement:

```
case "$(tail -n1 < "$f")" in
  (*"$string"*) cp -- "$f" file.new;;
  (*"$string2"*) cp -- "$f" file2.new;;
esac
```